# Pandas how to group data between a cumulative value reaching 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, columnsorting

I'm new to programming; and stepping into it with python; and heard it was best to learn as you do. So I've been playing around with a dataset and done most of my code; but learned that pandas has so many handy features that I haven't been taking advantage of;

I am hoping to group data between when a cumulative value hits 0; so data including the 0; and the data before it will be grouped; and the next bunch of data until cumulative value hits 0 will be grouped as well; its easier to see

this dataset;

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8], 'col2': [10, 1, -1, -10, 5, 1,-6,5] }
d = pd.DataFrame(d)

gives something like this; and I would like when col2 cum value reach 0; to group/rename col 1 entries by the first value that took it away from 0.

   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2     1
2     3    -1
3     4   -10
4     5     5
5     6     1
6     7    -6
7     8     5

So ideally something like this


   col1  col2  cumvalue
0     1    10        10
1     1     1        11
2     1    -1        10
3     1   -10         0
4     2     5         5
5     2     1         6
6     2    -6         0
7     3     5         5
```

I have tried df.groupby() but I just cant get the right syntax to get it! Thankyou!

Comment: I should also mention; that col1 doesn't have to be increasing in order- I would like it to group by col1 even if its random number (id)!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
d["cumvalue"] = d["col2"].cumsum()
d["col1"] = d["cumvalue"].eq(0).cumsum().shift().fillna(0).astype(int) + 1

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2  cumvalue
0     1    10        10
1     1     1        11
2     1    -1        10
3     1   -10         0
4     2     5         5
5     2     1         6
6     2    -6         0
7     3     5         5
```

Comment: tried it; worked perfectly!  I will need to learn how the shift/fill/astype works cause it seems very handy!

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by looping through each row in the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8], 'col2': [10, 1, -1, -10, 5, 1,-6,5] }
d = pd.DataFrame(d)

group_index = 1
cumvalue = 0

cumvalue_list = []
groupindex_list = []
for index, row in d.iterrows():
    groupindex_list.append(group_index)
    cumvalue = cumvalue + row['col2']
    cumvalue_list.append(cumvalue)
    
    if cumvalue == 0:
        group_index = group_index + 1
    
d['col1'] = groupindex_list
d['cumvalue'] = cumvalue_list

   col1  col2  cumvalue
0     1    10        10
1     1     1        11
2     1    -1        10
3     1   -10         0
4     2     5         5
5     2     1         6
6     2    -6         0
7     3     5         5
```

Comment: Im still new to this; but I was under the impression that using for loops in pandas is inefficient compared using its methods?

Comment: @Nekodas Yes this is definitely not the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
df['cumvalue'] = df['col2'].cumsum()
df['col1'] = df.groupby(df['cumvalue']==0).cumcount() + 1
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['cumvalue'] !=0).bfill().ffill().astype(int)
```

print(df):

```
   col1  col2  cumvalue
0     1    10        10
1     1     1        11
2     1    -1        10
3     1   -10         0
4     2     5         5
5     2     1         6
6     2    -6         0
7     2     5         5
```

Comment: worked to the request; but it doesnt update col1 till after cumvalue = 0, so I would like index 7 to be 3 value in col1